# How to close and fill Gulfs and inlets in QGIS or Grass?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, vector, filling

I have a raster layer from which I extracted only zones with a certain color, then polygonized it with QGis. I just generalized the new vector layer in GRASS to smooth things a bit.
There are many holes, "gulfs", "inlets" and cuts because the color zone in the raster overlays a black and white cartographic map. I would like to fill this spots, but I can't find a easy way. I already closed valid holes, but with "gulfs" and "inlets" I cannot use the same command.
[image: expample of cuts and inlets]

In that image, only the hole on the right is suposed to exist. Is there a easy way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One what that works fairly well is to buffer the feature(s) by distance x (approximately half of the largest 'inlet' you wish to fill) then inverse buffer the result to get back to the initial boundary.

Another option would be to use something like a 'grow' command on the raster before you convert to vector.

Comment: thanks! I didn't think of that, simple and effective solution!